# Сделать новый get запрос по каждой строчке после парсинга и вывести в файл

Tags: python

Есть такой код который парсит значения чисел:

```
import requests

headers = {

    'name': '40368324e9a4de4565b025dd7fa5ee97',
}

data = {
    'type': '1',
    'host': 'null',
}

response = requests.post('example.com/', headers=headers, data=data)



data = response.json()
with open('parse.txt', 'a') as file:
    for item in data['result']['list']:
        if item.get("number"):
             file.write(f'{item.get("number")}\n')
```

вывод такого вида:

```
1111111    
2222222  
3333333 
4444444
```

нужно каждое число по очереди вставлять в новый get запрос в котором параметру будет присваиваться эти числа

что то вроде этого:

```
get example.com?param={"number":1111111}
   time.sleep(5)
get example.com?param={"number":2222222}
```

после все результаты вывести в файл output.txt

Comment: Продолжайте использовать циклы для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
data = response.json()
with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
for x in [item.get("number") for item in data['result']['list'] if item.get("number")]:
    response = requests.get('example.com/', param={"number":x})
    file.write(response.text)
```